# django 1.3->1.4.6 staticfiles

Tags: django, django-admin

I made an automatic upgrade (debian rules, but sometimes kicks ...) of django, and now I can't get to admin part of my app...

after login (correct or not), the debug shows

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/
You're using the staticfiles app without having set the required STATIC_URL setting.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://django.zzzz.yy:83/wwwwwwww/admin/
Django Version: 1.4.5
Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value:    
You're using the staticfiles app without having set the required STATIC_URL setting.
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/utils.py in check_settings, line 49
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    
['/home',
 '/home/wwwwwwww',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']
```

I read lots of wise tutorials, so I know, that problem is with static files which are new in 1.4, but I definetely don't understand what is for and (which is more important to me) how to fix it..

the settings.py:

(...)

```
# Absolute path to the directory that holds media.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/"
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/media/'

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash if there is a path component (optional in other cases).
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# URL prefix for admin media -- CSS, JavaScript and images. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://foo.com/media/", "/media/".
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = "/var/www/static/"
STATIC_URL = "/static/"

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts',
)
```

(...)

and apache settings:

```
Alias /admin_media/ /usr/share/pyshared/django/contrib/admin/media/
```

When I made app (on 1.3) I create app from tutorial, and don't add any css or images -> just pure app - I use admin for editing objects (this is very early version - there's no interface yet - just views).

My apps are in /home:

/home/app1
/home/app2
/home/app3

(those apps are totally independent)

As far I understand static files are common for django apps (like .css of admin is the same for all apps)

So questions:

1. Where should I paste common files (and where they are now?
2. what setting should be changed?
3. where should I paste css dedicated to each app (in future, when I go out very development, and go to
   prerelease ;D

Comment: Are you using 1.4 just because that's the version Debian ships with?

Comment: yes. the highest stable

Comment: If you don't have any other constraints, consider developing your project in a [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/). You'll be able to work with the latest Django version while not modifying your system-wide version at all

Comment: Well, Nice tool, but I WANT to upgrade unintentionally :D The stable debian is really stable, but has rather old versions. So upgrading is always good. I upgrade debian every week, to have only one or two things to fix if it changes more than debian installer can fix itself. After this change everything works better, so it's not a bug it's a feature ;D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to answer each question individually, but will try to cover just enough of static files so you can actually use them properly.

First thing you should be aware of is what static files are supposed to be: CSS, Javascript, some images, files that won't change based on user interaction. Media files, on the other hand, are basically user-uploaded files, things that will change.

The `staticfiles` app is there to make it easier for you to have static files and multiple places but use them in an uniform manner, and also to easily serve them during development.

**Where to place static files**

Django uses the [`STATICFILES_FINDERS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#staticfiles-finders) setting to determine how to find your static files. By default, two finders are enabled: `FileSystemFinder` and `AppDirectoriesFinder`. The first looks for files in folders specified in [`STATICFILES_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#std%3asetting-STATICFILES_DIRS) and is pretty straightforward to use: add a directory to this setting, put a file in there and it's done.

The second finder, `AppDirectoriesFinder`, is more interesting: for any apps listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`, it will look for static files inside a folder named `static` inside each app. So, in your case, it would look for static files in `/home/app{1,2,3}/static`.

You can place your static files wherever you want, as long as you link to them somehow. If you're working on a standalone app, you want to use the `static` folder strategy, so you can easily distribute your app and all related files in one package, as the `admin` does. If you're working on apps specific to your project, you can choose any, or both. Go for the one that makes maintenance easier and causes least surprises (try to avoid the "Oh, I was sure this file was supposed to be here, but it's there instead").

**How to actually use this**

Start by removing the `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` setting, it was deprecated in 1.4 and is no longer in use in current versions.

After you have your static files somewhere, you can write, in the templates:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "some-css-file.css" %}">
```

That `{% static %}` tag will translate roughly to `{{STATIC_URL}}/some-css-file.css`, which uses whatever you define as `STATIC_URL` in the settings.

**Serving the files**

When you are using the development server (`python manage.py runserver`), Django will automatically serve static files from wherever they are to you. That is nice and all, but it won't work under Apache unless you explicitly tell Django to serve these even when `DEBUG` is `False`. But you probably [shouldn't to this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static-file-development-view) (read the "Warning").

Instead, you should use a management command called [`collectstatic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic). When you run this command, Django will go through the `static` folder for every app in `INSTALLED_APPS` and every folder in `STATICFILES_DIRS` and copy the contents to `STATIC_ROOT`. After that, you only have to add a rule in Apache that tells it where the files are. It should be something like this:

```
Alias STATIC_URL STATIC_ROOT
```

Or, using the values in your settings file:

```
Alias /static/ /var/www/static/
```

**Summary**

Now I'll answer the questions only:

1. It's up to you. You might want to put them in a separate folder (which you must specify in `STATICFILES_DIRS`) or use an app for that (one called "website", "common", or something else, up to you) and put them in the `static` folder inside;
2. From the settings, it seems like you've already changed what was needed (you included `STATIC_URL`). Just remember to remove `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX`. The admin static files will be copied too when you use `collectstatic`;
3. Put them in the `static` folder of the app, and run `collectstatic` in production to copy them to a place the webserver can see

Comment: Well, can I use both finders? /home/common form common files and /home/app{1,2,3}/static for static designed for each app? And how to set apache Alias /static/ -> /home/common?

Comment: Yes, it works - I not use collectstatic yet, but changing settings removes the error.

Comment: You can use both, in fact that's what's [enabled by default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#staticfiles-finders). In any case, you still have to call ``collectstatic`` before serving your files. Note that you're not supposed to have STATIC_ROOT be any folder that's in STATICFILES_DIRS, so if you have a "common" static files folder (suc h as ``/home/common``), you're expected to set STATIC_ROOT to something else (say, ``/home/static``). After that, use the Apache ``Alias`` to serve the folder. Check [this guide](http://bit.ly/1dYtkKS)